# How do I get this HTML canvas animation to appear on top of my image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

new to stack and coding, trying to create a simplified detective game (definitely have bitten off more than I can chew, but I decided to give it a shot anyway).

Here's a codepen link to the code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbZREp

*************** HTML *************************

None

************** CSS ***************************

```
body{
  background:#000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

****************JS ****************************

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var w = canvas.width = 800,
   h = canvas.height = 600;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://oi41.tinypic.com/4i2aso.jpg';

var background = new Image();
background.src = "https://i2.wp.com/i2.listal.com/image/2669447/500full.jpg";



var position = {x : w/3.2, y : h/2.5};

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var particles = [];
var random = function(min, max){
 return Math.random()*(max-min)*min;
};

/*canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
 position.x = e.offsetX;
 position.y = e.offsetY;
};*/
function Particle(x, y){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.velY = -2;
 this.velX = (random(1, 10)-5)/10;
 this.size = random(3, 5)/10;
 this.alpha = 1;
 this.update = function(){
   c.drawImage(background,0,0);
   this.y += this.velY;
   this.x += this.velX;
   this.velY *= 0.99;
   if(this.alpha < 0)
     this.alpha = 0;
   c.globalAlpha = this.alpha;
   c.save();
   c.translate(this.x, this.y);
   c.scale(this.size, this.size);
   c.drawImage(img, -img.width/2, -img.height/2);
   c.restore();
   this.alpha *= 0.96;
   this.size += 0.02;//
 };
}

var draw = function(){
 var p = new Particle(position.x, position.y);
 particles.push(p);

 while(particles.length > 500) particles.shift();

 c.globalAlpha = 2;
 c.drawImage(background,0,0);
 c.fillRect(0,0,w,h);



 for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
 {
   particles[i].update();
 }
};

setInterval(draw, 1000/60);
```

On codepen, if you comment out line 35 in the JS section, you'll see that there's a smoke animation BEHIND the detective's image (found it on codepen of course and thought it would make for a cool smoking animation). I was able to figure out how to get the detective image into the canvas, but I can't figure out how to get the smoke animation to appear in FRONT of detective's image. I've tried several methods including setting a Javascript picture onLoad, but out of all the methods, this is the closest I could get to my intended goal.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just draw the background image before you draw the particles:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var w = canvas.width = 800,
    h = canvas.height = 600;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://oi41.tinypic.com/4i2aso.jpg';

var background = new Image();
background.src = "https://i2.wp.com/i2.listal.com/image/2669447/500full.jpg";



var position = {x : w/3.2, y : h/2.5};

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var particles = [];
var random = function(min, max){
  return Math.random()*(max-min)*min;
};

/*canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
 position.x = e.offsetX;
 position.y = e.offsetY;
};*/
function Particle(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velY = -2;
  this.velX = (random(1, 10)-5)/10;
  this.size = random(3, 5)/10;
  this.alpha = 1;
  this.update = function(){
    //c.drawImage(background,0,0);
    this.y += this.velY;
    this.x += this.velX;
    this.velY *= 0.99;
    if(this.alpha < 0){this.alpha = 0;}
    c.globalAlpha = this.alpha;
    c.save();
    c.translate(this.x, this.y);
    c.scale(this.size, this.size);
    c.drawImage(img, -img.width/2, -img.height/2);
    c.restore();
    this.alpha *= 0.96;
    this.size += 0.02;//  
  };
}

var draw = function(){
  var p = new Particle(position.x, position.y);
  particles.push(p);

  // draw the background image before you draw the particles
  c.drawImage(background,0,0);

  while(particles.length > 500) particles.shift();

  for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
  {
    particles[i].update();
  }

};

setInterval(draw, 1000/60);
```

```css
body{ background-color: black; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much markE, I'll use this to try and dissect further into my project